# Larger batch size means faster training for RNN?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When training my LSTM, I realize time per eopch decreases as I increase the batch size. But this isn't true for training a ConvNet.

I wonder if this is because for RNNs with unspecified sequence length, everytime it train using a batch of data, it has to do the padding and compile a new graph of computation for that paticular batch. So larger batch size means fewer graph compiling and thus save the run time?

Comment: Do you still not observe a decrease in time for convNets if the batch size is increased frm 1 to 100 for ex?